# How to insert data into database table using upgradedata

Tags: magento2, database, setup-upgrade

I'm using **Magento 2.2.5** and I have a data set that I want to insert to database using **`upgrade data`** or **`install data`**.

How can I do this?

Am I able to use **object manager** to call the **model factory** and **insert** it from there?

Comment: Please have a look in to below post,  http://bilalusean.com/insert-data-upgrading-module-upgradedata-setup-script-magento-2/

Comment: Which type of data you have dynamic data? or some static  data can you explain more?